# How to customize error pages in Symfony for the Backend and Frontend?

Tags: php, symfony

I need to customize error pages in Symfony 2.8 depending on routes. I want one for the Frontend and one for the Backend.

Answer (score 0):

You should override (best will be extending current one and overriding specific methods - for example `showAction`)  exception controller and choose error template based on your criteria

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    exception_controller:  AppBundle:Exception:showException
```

Read more here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-the-default-exceptioncontroller